# Deactivate Jira users with Python

Tags: python, curl, python-requests, jira, jira-rest-api

I'm trying to deactivate jira users with Python.

I've found that I can deactivate jira users by running these 2 curl commands.

```
curl -s -c cookie_jar.txt -H "Content-Type: application/json" --data '{"username":"myAdminUserName", "password":"myAdminPassword"}' -X POST https://myBaseJiraUrl.atlassian.net/rest/auth/1/session

curl -s --cookie cookie_jar.txt  -H "Content-Type: application/json"  -X POST https://myBaseJiraUrl.atlassian.net/admin/rest/um/1/user/deactivate?username=userToDeactivate
```

I would like to do the same thing in python. Here is one of my attempts.

```
jiraSession = requests.Session()
username = jirausername
password = jirapass
userData = {'username': username, 'password': password}
baseURL = 'https://myBaseJiraUrl.atlassian.net'
jiraSession.post(baseURL + '/rest/auth/1/session', data=userData)
r3 = jiraSession.post(baseURL + '/admin/rest/um/1/user/deactivate?username={}'.format(user_name), auth=(username, password))
r5 = jiraSession.post(baseURL + '/admin/rest/um/1/user/deactivate?username={}'.format(user_name))
```

However it seems that I keep getting a 401 error response `User failed to authenticate`. I know it's not the credentials, because I use the same credentials in the curl request that works.

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong in my python code? Or know another way to deactivate a jira user through python?

Comment: you apparenetly do not pass the cookie

Comment: I suspected that might be it, do you know the correct way to do that with python?